# Kotlin - Call fragment method from MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have two fragments and a toolbar with a menu. I want to be able to switch fragments when a menu item is selected by calling the method in the fragment that does this. Problem is, I get this error when I try running the app with the code below. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FirstFragment{5ce330b (f5c2d362-d3fb-4346-9971-dd7be653e609)} not associated with a fragment manager.`

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var adapter: Adapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)

        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> {
                FirstFragment().settings()
                true
            }

            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

        }
    }
}
```

FirstFragment.kt

```
fun settings() {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
}
```

How can I implement a fragment manager so I can call this method via MenuItem and not get an exception? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason your `FirstFragment` isn't providing the `action_settings` MenuItem itself via the menu APIs on Fragment?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sorry... I'm still very new to Kotlin. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! I solved the issue by creating the MenuItem in my first fragment like so:

```
lateinit var second: MenuItem

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    second = menu.add("second fragment")

    second.setOnMenuItemClickListener() {
        settings()
        true
    }
}

fun settings() {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
}
```